# MacBook Pro 2018 High Temperature and CPU Usage with docker

Tags: macos, docker

I am using Macbook Pro 2018 and I am not sure if this is normal, but i am noticing a very high cpu usage and temperatures.

By Default: It was using 6 cores & `com.docker.hyperkit` was using 150%+ cpu
[https://imgur.com/pg78MFc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abHTL.jpg).

After reading little bit on google, I changed it to 1 Core and cpu usage went down to 60% but temperatures are still hot
[https://imgur.com/FYOv3iV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuK8p.jpg).

Can anyone confirm this and any solution for this?

Without docker temperatures are around 50.

Answer (score 7):

**Update**: I Fixed it by reinstalling OSX in `APFS` instead of `APFS Encrypted` and added `:cached` on mounted volumes.

Issue is happening when i am watching files inside mounted volumes (like watching typescript files for compilation or watching webpack files) then CPU is spiking and temperature is going above 80c.

**Before**

```
volumes:
      - .:/app/
```

**For fixing i added `:cached`**

```
volumes:
      - .:/app/:cached
```

Comment: what is the usage of com.docker.hyperkit right now?

Comment: @TarasLukavyi actually issue is with File sharing system that docker is using with host machine.
If i don't watch any files inside mounted volumes like example: watching typescripts file for compilation or watching webpack files, then it is working great. as soon as i start watching files inside containers , cpu is spiking and temp is going above 80c.

Comment: So, apfs doesnt help while watching?

Comment: Ye I think, it doesn't really help much